# Python output: how to remove indent of a new line?

Tags: python, output

There's an annoying little problem with Python `print()` output: the first line after `\n` is indented. Like this:

```
num = 888
print("The lucky number is:\n", num)

The lucky number is:
 888
```

I'd really like to have '888' aligned left. How can I do it?

Comment: Just use two `print` statements. Comma (`,`) automatically adds a space.

Comment: Or use one print with `sep` argument, see answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use string formatting to put `num` wherever you want in the string:

```
print(f"The lucky number is:\n{num}")
```

If f-strings aren't available to use, you can also use [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20format#str.format):

```
print("The lucky number is:\n{}".format(num))
```

And finally, while I don't recommend it because it's deprecated, you can use percentage symbol formatting:

```
print("The lucky number is:\n%d" % num)
```

Comment: @TerryA also this `print("The lucky number is:\n" + str(num))
`

Comment: I get the output aligned as I wish using the f-string method. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
print('The lucky number is:', num, sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
The lucky number is
888
```